# Angular9: Import of service not found in component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, angular-cdk

I've created a service that I use in 2 separate components from the same module.

The service has a few imports and is somewhat normal.

```
import { CdkPortal } from "@angular/cdk/portal";
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class TestService {...}
```

I've added the service into the module into the `providers` array as well as both components where the service is needed.

The first component uses the service with no issue.

```
import { FlyoutService } from "../flyout.service";

@Component({
  selector: "test-uno",
  templateUrl: "./test-uno.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test-uno.component.scss"],
})
export class TestUnoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private flyoutService: FlyoutService) {...}
}
```

The second component, that uses the service in what I think is the same way, fails.

```
import { FlyoutService } from "./../flyout.service";

@Component({
  selector: "test-dos",
  templateUrl: "./test-dos.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test-dos.component.scss"],
  animations: [...],
})
export class TestDosComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private flyoutService: FlyoutService) { }
}
```

The second component fails in the browser with the error:
`Export of name 'CdkPortal' not found.`

This only happens when buildOptimizer is set to true on the build. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: a question, why have you skipped adding `providedIn` inside injectible?

Comment: No particular reason, I've added it to the providers array in ```NgModule``` so I didn't see any need to.
Just to be sure though, I've tried with all options of ```providedIn``` and nothing really changes.

Comment: try adding `providedIn: "root"` and then try to integrate it

Comment: I've just tried it again, I get the same error: ```ERROR Error: Export of name 'cdkPortal' not found!```. No change from without the option.

Comment: um... spelling? you have imported `CdkPortal` but in your error it says `cdkPortal`

Comment: I don't have much experience with this but I think that's just how to directive is called. https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/api#CdkPortal

Am I missing something?

Edit: I've tried importing with lowercase 'c' and that doesn't exist. 
```@angular/cdk/portal"' has no exported member 'cdkPortal'. Did you mean 'CdkPortal'?```
Is there an extra step needed to import the directive? I've imported the module in my module: ```import {PortalModule} from '@angular/cdk/portal';```.